# Possible to Build With Imported COM Objects?

Tags: azure-devops

We have an application that utilises a third-party COM object (provided by a very well known finance/accounting software company).

In order to build this using VS on a dev machine yo must run tlbimport.

Is it possible to building this using DevOps builds on a MS hosted server, or do we need a self-hosted build server with the tlb file imported??

Comment: Hi Andrew Is my answer helpful to your issue?If you have any question, please feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

The  tlb import tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer).

Microsoft-hosted agent includes Hosted VS2017, HostedVS2019, etc. So I think you can build
this using DevOps builds on a MS hosted server.